# Cannot call extended method on JQuery object

Tags: jquery

I have HTML something like the following:

```
<div id="quoteContainer">
    <div class="quote prototype"></div>
     <div class="quote live q0"></div>
     <div class="quote live q1"></div>
     <div class="quote live q2"></div>
     <div class="quote live q3"></div>
     ...
</div>
```

Where each of the live divs are coppies of the prototype div. Here is the code that makes the copy:

```
quote = $(".quote.prototype").clone().show()
        .removeClass("prototype").addClass("live")
        .addClass(foo)
        .appendTo("#quoteContainer");

$.extend(quote, QuoteCalculator);
quote.setQuoteClass(foo);
```

Foo is a variable that combines "q" and the number of quotes. The QuoteCalculator class has several methods which I want to call, including (ex.) shout(). Here is part of QuoteCalculator:

```
var QuoteCalculator = {
    ...

    shout: function() {
        console.log("hello from calculator");
    },

    ...
};
```

At another point in the program, I want to call the shout method. Here is my code:

```
$(".quote.live").each(function() {
      this.shout();
});
```

Here is what firebug says: 
this.shout is not a function
[Break On This Error] this.shout();

EDIT: Here  is the weird part: calling quote.setQuoteClass(foo) does not generate an error. On the contrary, it works perfectly.

Why does the problem occur, what causes it, and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're expecting `quote` to be the DOM object - instead, it's a jQuery object referring to the DOM. Try this:

```
$.extend(quote.get(0), QuoteCalculator);
```

Comment: +1 I had not considered that possibility, but it makes sense as well. Either he is thinking he's extending the DOM element, or he thinks he's extending the jQuery prototype--neither of which is actually happening.

Comment: So the get would extend the DOM?

Comment: Thanks, I tried this and it solved the problem. +1 for being awesome.

Comment: That would extend the first DOM element matched by the selector used when `quote` was made.

Answer (score 3):

Your extend:

```
$.extend(quote, QuoteCalculator);
```

is extending an *instance* of the jQuery function.  It is *not* extending the jQuery prototype such that any new queries on elements that had been in the previous collection (`quote`) also get the methods.

```
$(".quote.live")
```

^^ that is a new query, resulting in a new instance of jQuery which is not connected to the instance you stored in `quote` which you extended.

You need to look into [plugin authoring](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring) and how to extend the jQuery "class" (the prototype of the jQuery function) so that all instances of jQuery returned by the factory have the methods you want.

Comment: If I'm not quite right that you are wanting to extend the jQuery prototype, then I think nrabinowitz hit the nail on the head with his answer.

Comment: I think what I want to do is extend the DOM rather than the prototype.